# Is there a way to add text captions/subtitles to my videos on MacOS? (burn in)

Tags: video-editor, mac, osx

I'm looking for a way to burn captions into videos without using Adobe Premiere (too expensive).

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Video Caption Maker**](http://www.videocaptionmaker.com) is free (with watermark). Otherwise you can hack together title screens and png's in iMovie which takes a bit of work.